# An example of a type with kind * -> * which cannot be an instance of Functor

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm very much a Haskell novice, so apologies if the answer is obvious, but I'm working through the Typeclassopedia in an effort to better understand categories. When doing the exercises for the section on Functors, I came across this problem:

> Give an example of a type of kind * -> * which cannot be made an instance of
>     Functor (without using undefined).

My first thought was to define some kind of infinitely recursing definition of fmap, but wouldn't that essentially be the same as if `undefined` was used in the definition?

If someone could explain the answer it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Source of original exercise here, section 3: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Introduction

Comment: What about `(-> int)`?

Comment: @RamonSnir `((->) Int)` is actually fine, you need something like `data K a = K (a -> Int)`.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov, that's almost certainly what Ramon means, just like `(+ 1) = \a -> a + 1`.

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov as @dbaupp noted, `(-> int)` <> `((->) int)`.

Comment: Operator sections aren't allowed with types last I checked, so `(-> Int)` is not valid syntax. Even if it were allowed, it would have to be treated as a partially-applied type synonym and thus couldn't be used for an instance without a wrapper type anyway. As an abuse of notation it makes perfect sense, though.

Comment: See also [Good examples of Not a Functor/Functor/Applicative/Monad?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7220436/1333025).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A simple example is

```
data K a = K (a -> Int)
```

Here's what ghci tells us is we try to automatically derive a `Functor` instance for `K`:

```
Prelude> :set -XDeriveFunctor
Prelude> data K a = K (a -> Int)
Prelude> :k K
K :: * -> *
Prelude> data K a = K (a -> Int) deriving Functor

<interactive>:14:34:
    Can't make a derived instance of `Functor K':
      Constructor `K' must not use the type variable in a function argument
    In the data type declaration for `K'
```

The problem is that the standard `Functor` class actually represents *covariant* functors (`fmap` lifts its argument to `f a -> f b`), but there is no way you can compose `a -> b` and `a -> Int` to get a function of type `b -> Int` (see Ramon's answer). However, it's possible to define a type class for contravariant functors:

```
class Contravariant f where
    contramap :: (a -> b) -> f b -> f a
```

and make `K` an instance of it:

```
instance Contravariant K where
    contramap f (K g) = K (g . f)
```

For more on covariance/contravariance in Haskell, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302739/covariance-contravariance-in-haskell).

**Edit:** Here's also [a nice comment on this topic](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1cht4v/what_does_coalgebra_mean_in_the_context_of/c9gzulr) from Chris Smith on Reddit.

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly, the issue is that for the fmap definition for K, we have `(a -> b) -> K (a -> Int) -> K (a -> b)` which  would be defined by attempting to compose a function of type `a -> Int` and a function of type `a -> b`, which doesn't work because type `a` would have to be fixed to `Int`?

Comment: @JS You have a function of type `a -> b` and a function of type `a -> Int`, and you must produce a function of type `b -> Int`. But there is no way you can compose the inputs to get the desired output.

Comment: No need to define the `Contravariant` class, use [the one from Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/contravariant/0.4/doc/html/Data-Functor-Contravariant.html#g:1)!

Answer (score 6):

To expand on my (short) comment and on Mikhail's answer:

Given `(-> Int)`, you'd expect `fmap` to look as such:

```
(a -> Int) -> (a -> b) -> (b -> Int)
```

or:

```
(a -> Int) -> (a -> b) -> b -> Int
```

It is easy to prove that from the three arguments `(a -> Int)`, `(a -> b)`, `b` there is no possible way to reach `Int` (without `undefined`), thus from `(a -> Int)`, `(a -> b)` there is no way to reach `(b -> Int)`. Conclusion: no `Functor` instance exists for `(-> Int)`.

Comment: The proof is simply: We have two theorems, both require proof for `a`. We only have a proof for `b`. No new proofs can be derived (as none of the theorems is applicable) => no proof can be derived for `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble with this one, and I found Ramon and Mikhail's answers informative -- thanks! I'm putting this in an answer rather than a comment because 500 chars is too short, and for code formatting.

I was having trouble understanding what was covariant about `(a -> Int)` and came up with this counterexample showing `data K a = K (a -> Int)` *can* be made an instance of Functor (disproving Ramon's proof)

```
data K a = K (a -> Int)
instance Functor K where
  fmap g (K f) = K (const 0)
```

If it compiles, it must be correct, right? ;-)
I spent some time trying other permutations. Flopping the function around just made it easier:

```
-- "o" for "output"
-- The fmapped (1st) type is a function output so we're OK.
data K0 o = K0 (Int -> o)
instance Functor K0 where
  fmap :: (oa -> ob) -> (K0 oa) -> (K0 ob)
  fmap g (K0 f) = K0 (g . f)
```

Turning the Int into a type variable reduced it to Section 3.2 exercise 1 part 2:

```
-- The fmapped (2nd) type argument is an output
data K1 a b = K1 (a -> b)
instance Functor (K1 a) where
  fmap :: (b1 -> b2) -> K1 a b1 -> K1 a b2
  fmap g (K1 f) = K1 (g . f)
```

Forcing the fmapped type to be an argument of the function was the key... just like Mikhail's answer said, but now I understand it ;-)

```
-- The fmapped (2nd) type argument is an input
data K2 a b = K2 (b -> a) 
instance Functor (K2 o) where
  fmap :: (ia -> ib) -> (K2 o ia) -> (K2 o ib)
  -- Can't get our hands on a value of type o
  fmap g (K2 f) = K2 (const (undefined :: o))
  -- Nor one of type ia
  fmap g (K2 f) = K2 (const (f (undefined :: ia)))
```